# Variable Length Argument Parsing with getopt() in C

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to implement a multi layer perceptron library in C and i would like to set the number of hidden layers and the number of perceptrons in each layer from command line with the flag -H where the first number is the number of hidden layers and the following next 2 numbers are the numbers of neurones in that 2 layers respectively, i am using getopt()
For example if i  want to create a network with 2 hidden layers each with 5 neurones i will type: -H 2 5 5
for 3 layers with 5, 4 and 3 neurones respectively i will pass -H 3 5 4 3

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":d:i:o:h:")) != -1) {
  switch (opt) {
  case 'd':
    printf("dataset file: %s\n", optarg);
    break;
  case 'i':
    printf("number of inputs: %s\n", optarg);
    break;
  case 'h':
    // Help need parsing the options here
    break;
  case 'o':
    printf("number of outputs %s\n", optarg);
    break;
  case '?':
    printf("Unknown option: %c\n", optopt);
    break;
  case ':':
    printf("Missing arg for %c\n", optopt);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: error handling code also appriciated in case user passed too little or more numbers of neurones

Comment: `getopt()` only supports a single argument. Use a different parser, or maybe require the values to be comma-separated or whatever and split them up later?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, the standard convention of 'getopt' is to have one value per option. If you MUST deliver the `-h 2 5 4 3` option, consider the following code, which manipulate the optind to skip over the extra values after the '-h'.

```
int nLayers = 0 ;
int *layers = NULL ;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":d:i:o:h:")) != -1) {
  switch (opt) {
  ...
  case 'h':
    nLayers = atoi(optarg) ;
    layers = calloc(nLayers, sizeof(*layers)) ;
    for (int i=0 ; i<optarg ; i++ ) {
        layers[i] = atoi(argv[optind++]) ;
    } ;
    // Parse Hidden Layers
    break;


  ...
  case ':':
    printf("Missing arg for %c\n", optopt);
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that the above code does not perform any checks for numeric values.

Also consider '-h 5,4,3' as alternative to '-h 5 -h 4 -h 3' suggestion, using strtok to parse the option values.

```
int nLayers = 0 ;
int *layers = NULL ;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":d:i:o:h:")) != -1) {
  switch (opt) {
  ...
  case 'h':
    // Parse Hidden Layers
    for ( char *p = strtok(optval, ",") ; p != NULL ; p = strtok(NULL, ",") ) {
        nLayers++ ;
        layers = realloc(layers, sizeof(*layers)*nLayers) ;
        layers[nLayers-1] = atoi(p) ;
    } ;
    break;


  ...
  case ':':
    printf("Missing arg for %c\n", optopt);
    break;
  }
}
```